# Remove multiple elements from an array using a function

Tags: javascript, arrays

What I am trying to do is to return the [1, 4] array, however, I do not understand what's the mistake which ends up returning [1]. Any clues? Thank you!

```js
const removeFromArray = function(arr) {
  for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    arr.splice(arr[i], 2);
  }
  return arr;
};
console.log(
  removeFromArray([1, 2, 3, 4], 3, 2)
)
```

Comment: You are not using the second and third arguments and removing 2 items in every loop.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do not understand how to use the 2nd and 3rd arguments

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear to me what you want to achieve.
You define a function which only takes one argument:

```
const removeFromArray = function(arr) {...}
```

But then you call the function with 3 arguments, an array and two numbers:

```
removeFromArray([1, 2, 3, 4], 3, 2)
```

Now your function only takes the first input (the array) and removes all elements instead the first one.

Please consider the syntax: `splice(start, deleteCount)`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: Even if I set two more parameters in the function eg element1 and element2, the result is the same, because I simply cannot get how to include them/use them in the loop. I am completely stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this `rm()` does what you want?

```js
const rm=(arr, ...rem)=>arr.filter(a=>!rem.includes(a));

console.log(rm([1, 2, 3, 4], 3, 2));
```

It treats the first argument as the array `arr` that is to be filtered. The following arguments then make up the array `rem`, containing all the elements that are to be taken out of array `arr`.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using the built in filter method for arrays.

```
removeFromArray = (array, unwanted, otherUnwanted) => {
  const filtered = array.filter((number) => {
     return number !== unwanted && number !== otherUnwanted
  });

  return filtered;
};

console.log(removeFromArray[1,2,3,4], 3, 2]
```

To make the function more scalable for future use the second parameter could be an array.

```
betterRemoveFromArray = (array, unwantedNumbers) => {
  const filtered = array.filter((number) => {
    return !unwantedNumbers.includes(number)
  });

  return filtered;
};

console.log(removeFromArray3([1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a variadic function which means it accepts a variable number of arguments. To represent it, use the [rest parameter syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) which allows the function to accept an indefinite number of arguments as an array.
Then, use the filter method on the 1st argument, like so:

```
const removeFromArray = function(arr, ...theArgs) {
    arr = arr.filter(arg => !theArgs.includes(arg));
    return arr;
};
console.log(
  removeFromArray([1, 2, 3, 4], 3, 2)
)
```